# Multi Page PDF export of a Silverlight UI using SilverPDF

Tags: silverlight, pdf, itext

This is my first post and I'm really frustrated using Silverlight just because I'm a newbie in this.

I have three Silverlight UI (StackPanels basically) "stkMain1", "stkMain2" and "stkMain3".

I have to convert these three stack panels to PDF. I'm using silverPDF (I guess it further uses iTextSharp and PDFSharp.)

I've written the following code :

```
Private Sub cmdImage_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles cmdImage.Click
    Dim d As New SaveFileDialog()
    d.Filter = "PDF file format|*.pdf"

    ' Save the document...
    If d.ShowDialog() = True Then
        stkMain.Children.Clear()
        stkMain.Children.Add(stkMain1)

        Dim document As New PdfDocument()
        Dim page As PdfPage = document.AddPage
        Dim gfx As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
        Dim img As ImageTools.ExtendedImage = BillPage1.ToImage
        Dim mstream As New MemoryStream()
        Dim encoder As New JpegEncoder()
        encoder.Encode(img, mstream)
        mstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Dim pdfImg As XImage = XImage.FromStream(mstream)
        gfx.DrawImage(pdfImg, 0, 0)

    End If
End Sub
```

This does everything correct and gives one PDF file with one page.. Superb output and Thumbs up.
Now the real problem starts:

```
Private Sub cmdImage_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles cmdImage.Click
    Dim d As New SaveFileDialog()
    d.Filter = "PDF file format|*.pdf"

    ' Save the document...
    If d.ShowDialog() = True Then
        stkMain.Children.Clear()
        stkMain.Children.Add(BillPage1)

        Dim document As New PdfDocument()
        Dim page As PdfPage = document.AddPage
        Dim gfx As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
        Dim img As ImageTools.ExtendedImage = BillPage1.ToImage
        Dim mstream As New MemoryStream()
        Dim encoder As New JpegEncoder()
        encoder.Encode(img, mstream)
        mstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Dim pdfImg As XImage = XImage.FromStream(mstream)
        gfx.DrawImage(pdfImg, 0, 0)


        document.Pages.Add()

        Dim page1 As PdfPage = document.AddPage
        Dim gfx1 As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page1)
        Dim img1 As ImageTools.ExtendedImage = BillPage2.ToImage
        Dim mstream1 As New MemoryStream()
        Dim encoder1 As New JpegEncoder()
        encoder1.Encode(img1, mstream1)
        mstream1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Dim pdfImg1 As XImage = XImage.FromStream(mstream1)
        gfx1.DrawImage(pdfImg1, 0, 0)


        document.Save(d.OpenFile())
    End If
End Sub
```

Now this creates Two pages, and I get a scrambled output, contents of the stackpanels overlapping each other.

How to solve this?? I NEED HELP DESPERATELY. THE PROJECT IS DUE AND I HAVE TO SUBMIT IT BY 26th March 2011 (MONDAY).

Thanks in advance
Ravi

Comment: Can you explain what your output looks like a little more? I don't know Silverlight too well but it looks like you're convert a UI element to an element and adding that to a single page in a PDF, then repeating that with the next UI element, right? Is the first page OK? Is it just the second page that look bad? What's overlapping what? Is it a problem in the PDF or in the image creation? Have you tried saving the images to disk manually to see if they're OK their?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
If d.ShowDialog() = True Then
    Dim document As New PdfDocument()
    Dim page As PdfPage = document.AddPage
    Dim pdfImg As XImage = DrawUI(stkMain1)
    gfx.DrawImage(pdfImg, 20, 20)
    page = document.AddPage()
    gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
    pdfImg = DrawUI(stkMain2)
    page = document.AddPage()
    gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
    gfx.DrawImage(pdfImg, 20, 20)
    pdfImg = DrawUI(stkMain3)
    gfx.DrawImage(pdfImg, 20, 20)
    document.Save(d.OpenFile())
End If


Private Function DrawUI(ByVal oControl As Object) As XImage
    Dim img As ImageTools.ExtendedImage = ImageExtensions.ToImage(oControl)
    Dim mstream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim encoder As New JpegEncoder()
    encoder.Encode(img, mstream)
    mstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    Dim pdfImg As XImage = XImage.FromStream(mstream)
    Return pdfImg
End Function
```